Separating shared databases and making them independent
I have a multi-store platform, but the databases for all the stores are shared. I want to know how I can separate them so that each store has its own separate and independent database while keeping some data in shared databases, such as the number of stores we have and sales statistics, etc. How can I perform this operation while using SQL and Laravel?
I have searched, but I didn't find any useful information.

it seems like you are trying to build multi-tenancy app. you can use library such as stancl/tenancy library for Laravel. you can find it here. for multiple database you see the url multi-database-tenancy.
if you want to create without library or you have already build app you can use this solution.
create env for 2 database connections. here is an example.
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

SHARED_CONNECTION=mysql
SHARED_HOST=127.0.0.1
SHARED_PORT=3306
SHARED_DATABASE=laravel
SHARED_USERNAME=root
SHARED_PASSWORD=

go to database.php config file
inside the connections array add the line
'shared' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('SHARED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('SHARED_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('SHARED_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('SHARED_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('SHARED_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
    ],

Now create a table in SHARED database so that config will store there. table column could be, domain_host, db_host, port, db_name,username, password,
after creating the table, create a middleware where the original database .env variable can be overridden. here is an example
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
class LoadTenantConfiguration
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $domain_host = $request->getHost();

        $config = DBConfig::where("domain_host", $domain_host)->first();
        
        config()->set('database.connections.mysql.host', $config->host);
        config()->set('database.connections.mysql.port', $config->port);
        config()->set('database.connections.mysql.database', $config->database);
        config()->set('database.connections.mysql.username', $config->username);
        config()->set('database.connections.mysql.password', $config->password);

        return $next($request);
    }
}

in the DBConfig model set $connection to shared.
if you have another table in the shared database you have to set the connection to shared.
protected $connection = "shared"

you can also change the driver if the database exists in a different database than MySQL.
Don't forget to add middleware in the middleware group array.
